# The Newsstand app's Info.plist must contain UINewsstandApp.error.message=true

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, newsstand-kit

I'm getting the below error message in iTunes connect while I'm trying to upload my app. Everywhere I have read tells me just to remove the NewsstandIcon under `CFBundleIcon` in `info.plist`. I have done this and still get the same error code. Im a novice when it comes to code so if you can help please give me a full description of how to do it. Below is the full error message:

> The Newsstand app's Info.plist must contain UINewsstandApp.error.message=true and a CFBundleIcons.UINewsstandIcon dictionary. For more information, see the Information Information Property List Key Reference.
>   To use the 'newsstand-content' background mode, your app must be enabled for Newsstand. For more information, see the Information Information Property List Key Reference.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution:
my app doesn't need the Newsstand functionalities.
I've added an icon into iTunesConnect to fill the white space, and this automatically activate Newsstand.
After disabling it, I can normally submit app for review! ;)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Application -> Click 'Info', which is next to Build Settings -> 
Open 'Required background modes' Array and delete the item with the name contains 'Newstand'.